# How to Deserialize JSON Array

Tags: vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

there I am having difficulty deserializing a json array.  The array is derived from the following classes

```
Public Class PIValues
     Inherits List(Of PIValue)

     Public Sub New()
     End Sub
End Class

Public Class PIValue

     Private _PointName As String
     Private _value As Double
     Private _timeStamp As String

     Public Property PointName() As String
         Get
            PointName = _PointName
         End Get
          Set(value As String)
             _PointName = value
         End Set
     End Property
     Public Property TimeStamp() As String
        Get
            TimeStamp = _timeStamp
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _timeStamp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Value() As Double
        Get
            Value = _value
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _value = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The above is held as AssemblyName.PIValue and AssemblyName.PIValues which are part of the same solution

Implementation of this code within my unit tests results in the following json array held in the string `result`:

> [{\"PointName\":\"MW Tag
>   1\",\"TimeStamp\":\"20200128073000\",\"Value\":-0.0015},{\"PointName\":\"MW Tag
>   2\",\"TimeStamp\":\"20200128073000\",\"Value\":-0.0031},{\"PointName\":\"MW Tag
>   3\",\"TimeStamp\":\"20200128073000\",\"Value\":-2.1485},{\"PointName\":\"MW Tag
>   4\",\"TimeStamp\":\"20200128073000\",\"Value\":0.0}]

I had expected to be able to use the newtonsoft library in the following way for deserialization:

```
 Dim Items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PIValue())(result)
```

However this does not work.  I am new to using the newtonsoft library, would appreciate any assistance

Kind Regards
Paul.

Comment: Your code seems valid. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? does it throw an exception (if so, add the exception message to your question) or is it something else?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not sufficient to form a good question here on SO. You'll want to read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @InteXX and HeyJude - Once I got the syntax worked out I actually managed to get things to work, hence me posting an answer to my problem, however the joy was shortlived as you will see from the comments against my answer I am now getting a casting error from newtonsoft...

Answer (score 1):

We can't know what you mean by "doesn't work," but this code runs without error and emits a JSON string identical to the one you've provided:

```
Public Module Main
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim oPIValues1 As PIValues
    Dim oPIValues2 As PIValues
    Dim sResult As String

    oPIValues1 = New PIValues From {
      New PIValue With {.PointName = "MW Tag 1", .TimeStamp = "20200128073000", .Value = -0.0015},
      New PIValue With {.PointName = "MW Tag 2", .TimeStamp = "20200128073000", .Value = -0.0031},
      New PIValue With {.PointName = "MW Tag 3", .TimeStamp = "20200128073000", .Value = -2.1485},
      New PIValue With {.PointName = "MW Tag 4", .TimeStamp = "20200128073000", .Value = -0.0000}
    }

    sResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oPIValues1)
    oPIValues2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PIValues)(sResult)

    Console.WriteLine(sResult)
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
End Module



Public Class PIValues
  Inherits List(Of PIValue)
End Class



Public Class PIValue
  Public Property PointName As String
  Public Property TimeStamp As String
  Public Property Value As Double
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok...  So I sussed it, the answer is:

Dim dser As List(Of PIValue) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of PIValue))(result)

Comment: The cast of `dser` to `List(Of PIValue)` is good design in general, but it isn't necessary for this particular code. `Dim dser = ...` is valid as well, and if you hover over the `dser` variable on the code canvas you'll see that it receives a cast by implication.

Comment: Ok, spoke too soon, now getting a casting error:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "[{"PointName":"M~Maelor Creamery~33-11kV T1~11kV CB~MW~DA30","TimeStamp":"20200128130000","Value":2.536}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SPEN.PIValue]'. Path '', line 1, position 117.'

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SPEN.PIValue]...

Cant understand why it would work one moment and then stop working the next :-/

Comment: @PaulJohnson, it should actullay work, as in this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nCaKz9).

Comment: `PIValues` inherits from `List(Of PIValue)`, so while either one will work, casting to the former is preferable. The JSON string that you've provided works with HeyJude's .NET Fiddle. Did you try the code that I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Again, you're withholding necessary information from us and then asking us to help you solve your problem with insufficient data. You seem to like to do that ;-) What's the code that's producing the error?

Comment: Apologies InteXX.  Here is the code that generates the error:

            Dim dser As List(Of PIValue) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of PIValue))(result)

Comment: Right, it looks like the issue is data related.  The sanitised verison of the code that I provided works as expected.  So that got me looking at the real tags. The real tags have the format:

a~locationname~descriptor~nomenclature~engunit~datatype

It looks like newtonsoft may be complaining about the '~'.  is this a reserved character perhaps?

Comment: I didn't see your replies until just now, when I happened by chance to look at the conversation. To avoid this in the future, you'll want to `@mention` the person you're addressing, so that he'll receive a notification in his inbox. That said, I ran the string you provided earlier—`[{"PointName":"M~Maelor Creamery~33-11kV T1~11kV CB~MW~DA30","TimeStamp":"20200128130000","Value":2.536}]` (including the tildes)—through HeyJude's .NET Fiddle. It worked just fine. Question of the hour: have you tried the code that either of us has suggested?

Comment: p.s. You don't need to `@mention` in a comment that's in direct response to a Q or an A. That author automatically receives a notification. Another minutia, the one you ran into: when a conversation between an author and a commenter involves only those two persons, the commenter need not `@mention`. Notifications for these are sent automatically. It's only when a third party comments that this automation ceases and an explicit `@mention` is required in the comment (e.g. I received a notification for your first comment reply here—the one with the string—but neither the second nor the third).